# Codeigniter with datamapper save error

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I was trying to make a CRUD for my app. I have setup a controller, like this:

```
class Clients extends CI_Controller {


public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    session_start();
    $this->c = new Client();
    $this->u = new User();
}

function index() {
    $data['current_view'] = 'client_view';
    $data['header'] = 'Меню клиентов';

    $data['clients'] = $this->getClients();

    $this->load->view('main_view',$data);
}

function getClients() {

    $this->u->where('username',$_SESSION['username'])->get();

    $c = $this->c->where('user_id',$this->u->id)->get();

    return $c;
}

function delClient() {
    $this->c->where('client_id', $this->uri->segment(3))->delete();

    $this->c->skip_validation()->save();

    $this->index();
}

}
```

However, when I'm trying to perform a delete on a client, i get a db error:

> You must use the "set" method to update an entry.
>
> Filename: C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\system\database\DB_active_rec.php
>
> Line Number: 1174

What might be the cause of this? I found a similar question here, but I don't think that's the case.

EDIT: Client model:

```
class Client extends DataMapper {

public $has_one = array('user');

public function __construct($id = NULL) {
   parent::__construct($id);
}

}
```

Comment: What is in your `Client()` and `User()` ? are they your models ?

Comment: @Deepak Yes, they are simple Datamapper ORM models based on its abstract class.

Comment: When you call `$this->c->skip_validation()->save();` what code gets executed ?

Comment: can you paste your `Client` class code ?

Comment: @Deepak I pasted the model, as you see it's pretty simple. The methods are inherited.

Comment: does `$this->uri->segment(3)` this have a value in it and not null?

Comment: @plainjane yes, it corresponds to the client_id. The url is /clients/delClient/1 for the first client_id.

Answer (score 0):

you have not passed the uri segment to the function `delClient()` and this is your model right...

```
function delClient($id) {
  //$id is the value which you want to delete
  $this->c->where('client_id', $id)->delete();

  $this->c->skip_validation()->save();

  $this->index();
}
```

Comment: $id here corresponds to what? Sorry, i'm not really good at this.

Comment: where are you calling the model in your controller? $id corresponds to the `$this->uri->segment(3)` which is passed in the calling the `delClient()` in your controller

Comment: How do i pass it correctly? Honestly, I'm not sure if it's needed.

 I'm not calling the model directly, i'm guessin.

Comment: I just create two objects based on the models, and everything else is being handled by the datamapper.

Comment: google for this error i guess it just a small mistake i googled it and mostly empty data is sent for updation or deletion